# Are subdomains included in a Private Domain for Marketing Cloud without SAP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, custom-domain, mydomain

Based on this article:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318538&type=1

When I get a private domain out of SAP, are subdomains like campaign.company.com or mail.company.com included? In case the domain was company.com

Also, in the same article, it states "Private Domains allow you to send mail from an authenticated domain (including SPF and DKIM) or to brand your CloudPages"

Does a private domain include Sending AND Cloudpages or it is Sending OR Cloudpages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subdomains are not included.

> Note: Don’t just make up sub-domain names. If company-email.com is the SAP domain, and you want to add “order.company-email.com” -- it must be set up as private domain. It will not just “automatically work” because the top level domain is hosted by us. There is no sub-domain/domain “inheritance” with SAP or Private Domain.

source is a presentation from SF I found in my notes.

==

Private Domains are for either Sending OR Cloudpages.

> Private Domains allow you to send mail from an authenticated domain (including SPF and DKIM) or to brand your CloudPages.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318538&type=1

This "or" is meant verbatim - You have to actually specify this when requesting this at SF support. This is an excerpt from the "form" they sent us once:

> Do you intend to use the private domain for sending email, classic content microsites, or CloudPages? Note: the private domain can only be used for one or the other.